# Android onKeyDown

Tags: android, onkeydown

In my application I have written the onkeyDown method to handle my menus and back button, It works fine when the activity in which it is written works fine, but when I move any other activity and then return back to this activity again then this method doesnot works.

Please let me know what is my mistake or what is the possible solution??

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


        if(mExpandableListView.isGroupExpanded(commonGroupPosition)&& keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){

            if(mllpopmenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Chat Expanded Menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else{

                if(commonGroupPosition>=4){

                    mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    mlist2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(UserMenuActivity.this,
                            R.layout.listviewtext, R.id.tvMenuText,
                            data_Contact));

                }

                else if(commonGroupPosition==1){

                    mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    mlist2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(UserMenuActivity.this,
                            R.layout.listviewtext, R.id.tvMenuText,
                            data_child_contact));

                }



            }

            return true;
        }

        else{

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
                if (mllpopmenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                else if(commonGroupPosition==0){

                    mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mlist2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(UserMenuActivity.this,
                            R.layout.listviewtext, R.id.tvMenuText, data));

                }

                return true;

            }

        }



        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

            //Toast.makeText(UserMenuActivity.this, "Returning..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (mllpopmenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                if (CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection.isConnected()) {
                    //super.onBackPressed();

                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);      
                    alertDialog.setTitle("CCM Logout");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
                    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                    //Ok button for Logout
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection.disconnect();

                            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,UpdaterService.class);
                            stopService(serviceIntent);

                            //CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection.removeConnectionListener(arg0);
                            finish();

                        }
                    });

                    //Cancel button
                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            dialog.cancel();                        
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();

                }

            }

            return true;

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: "then this method does not work" what does this mean exactly?  The method is not called?  It doesn't do what you expect?  It crashes?  "Does not work" is not a good description of the problem.

Comment: Its done now. I got the solution

Comment: could you please give the solution...

Answer (score 0):

I think it may because of your return value of the onKeydown() method.If you handled the event, return true. If you want to allow the event to be handled by the next receiver, return false. I guess it might work if you change you return value to true.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown(int, android.view.KeyEvent)

Wish it could work. :)